# Linked List Insertion Simple

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
   int key;
   struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef node_t* node_ptr;

void main()
{
    node_ptr p = NULL;
    node_ptr listhead =NULL;

    /*need to create a listhead with key = 1,2,3..10*/

    int i; 
    for (i =1; i<= 10;i ++) 
    {
       node_ptr temp;
       p =(node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
       p->key = i;
       p->next = NULL;
       if( list_head == NULL ) 
       {
         list_head= p;   
       }
       else
       {
       temp = listhead;

         while(temp->next != NULL)
         {
           temp = temp->next;
         }
         temp->next =  p;
       }
    }
}
```

I am still pretty confused about linked list and I am not sure if I'm doing correctly and pretty sure it is wrong, could anyone help me out? This is just
a practice question :)
And also uptil the line of node_ptr listhead=NULL; is given in the question so i cannot change the stuffs above that.

By the way just to be clear, the question asks to insert keys 1,2,3..10 to the listhead.

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind `typedef`. It is error-prone.

Comment: `p->key = i;` Undefined behavior: You're dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Also, you either use int main(int argc, char **argv) or go int main(void).

Comment: Uptil the node_ptr listhead= NULL  line, it is given in the question so I think I can not change those.. :(

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your list elements. You are not allocating it in your code.

Comment: You need to review any of the *thousands* of examples online that build simple linked lists. Your problem will be obvious. There is no dynamic allocation in this code, yet you treat the pointers as if they refer to valid memory.

Comment: @melpomene - In this case, the typedef for the pointer was given as part of the assignment. With a name like node_ptr, it shouldn't be an issue. Windows API also uses pointer typedefs, like LPCTSTR, so it's not that uncommon.

Comment: @rcgldr: Just because it is quantitatively common, does not mean it is a good practice. The same can be said about the habit of casting the result of `malloc`: it is a bad, but rather sticky practice, widely encountered in poor quality code and low-grade learning materials. BTW, can the author of the above code explain why they used `node_ptr` in some contexts and yet `node_t *` in others (like `malloc` casts)? No they can't. They just mindlessly followed a *cargo cult*, without understanding what they were doing.

Comment: @AnT - the assignment defines node_ptr. The OP's code should have also used `node_ptr` instead of `node_t *` to be consistent with the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Insert" can imply inserting at the start of a list rather than at some point in the list or at the end of a list. For this assignment, what is "insert" supposed to mean?

Example code with for loop and minor changes like using node_ptr instead of node_t * to correspond with assignment typedef, and int main() instead of void main().

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int key;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef node_t* node_ptr;

int main()
{
    node_ptr list_head = NULL;
    node_ptr p;
    node_ptr temp;
    int i; 

    /* create a list with keys = 1,2,3..10 */

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    {
        p = (node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        p->key = i;
        p->next = NULL;
        if( list_head == NULL ) 
        {
            list_head= p;   
        }
        else
        {
            for(temp = list_head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next);
            temp->next =  p;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternate version using pointer to pointer to node. This eliminates the initial check for list_head == NULL. It's beyond what you'd be using now for the assignment, but knowing how to do this could be useful in later assignments.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int key;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef node_t* node_ptr;
typedef node_t ** node_ptr_ptr;

int main()
{
    node_ptr list_head = NULL;
    node_ptr p;
    /* ptr to either list_head or to last node.next */
    node_ptr_ptr pptemp;
    int i; 
    /* create a list with keys = 1,2,3..10 */
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    {
        p = (node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        p->key = i;
        p->next = NULL;
        for(pptemp = &list_head; *pptemp != NULL; pptemp = &(*pptemp)->next);
        *pptemp =  p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this particular case, since temp (or pptemp) is in main, it only needs to be initialized once and advanced once per loop:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int key;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef node_t* node_ptr;
typedef node_t ** node_ptr_ptr;

int main()
{
    node_ptr list_head = NULL;
    node_ptr p;
    /* ptr to either list_head or to last node.next */
    node_ptr_ptr pptemp = &list_head;
    int i; 
    /* create a list with keys = 1,2,3..10 */
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    {
        p = (node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        p->key = i;
        p->next = NULL;
        *pptemp = p;
        pptemp = &p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question states that we  just need to create a linked list with those keys and I believe end of the list would be appropriate in this case. sorry for not being clear in the first place.

Comment: I have changed the code abit , is it like better or am i going in a completely wrong direction ? :D

Comment: just altered it back again, hopefully its correct now, I found some similar codes on other sites as well but if you dont mind, could you explain why do we need the "temp", i mean if we write it that way, only the temp would be updated but not the "listhead"?

Comment: @AlvissMin - I updated my answer to show some alternatives you could use in the future. I also deleted my prior comments since they aren't needed anymore.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks alot :) Sorry for the trouble again :D